# gdal_calc raster calculcator : "any" syntax

Tags: raster, gdal, qgis-3, raster-calculator, gdal-calc

I'm trying to combine 2 raster layers using gdal_calc in order to use them in QGIS 3.8.
One of the condition that has to be met could be translated as "if the value of raster A is 1 and the value of raster B is either 10 or 11 or... or 800 (I've got 20 different values or so), then keep the value of raster B".

I managed to achieve what I wanted using several logical_and :

`logical_and(A==1,B==10)*B + logical_and(A==1,B==11)*B + ... + logical_and(A==1,B==800)*B`

But it's tedious to write and hard to read for other users. Is there a way to get the same result using a more compact syntax ? 
I tried using

`logical_and(A==1,any(B==[1,10,11,12,33,35,41,42,43,44,51,52,53,222,223,224,602,700,702,710,800]))*B` and `logical_and(A==1,B==any([1,10,11,12,33,35,41,42,43,44,51,52,53,222,223,224,602,700,702,710,800]))*B`

But neither of these gave me the same result as my previous lengthy expression...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a more compact writing could be

```
B*(A==1)*((B==10)+(B==11)+...+(B==800))
```

but this would still be quite long.

For me, **any** is not the good command but you could use **isin** (not tested)

```
B*(A==1)*(isin(B,[10,11,...,800]))
```

Comment: Just tried it, and it works! Thank you. Would you, by chance, have any good resource suggestions to learn the commands that one can use with gdal_calc? I used scipy.org, but it's rather difficult for me to figure out what I need using this website, considering I'm not familiar with the syntax and sometimes have no idea about the name of the command I'm looking for...

Comment: I am more familiar with otbcli_BandMath https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/Applications/app_BandMath.html , =i suggest that you have a look at it. Otherwise, you should refer to the numpy help.

Comment: I'll have look at it. Thanks !